# undefined method `_run_suites' for class `Minitest::Unit' (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rspec, nitrousio

I've been trying to use Rspec in my ROR webapp, but I can't run tests locally only on nitrous.io

Log on my computer:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/parallel_each.rb:67:in `<class:Unit>': undefined method `_run_suites' for class `Minitest::Unit' (NameError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/parallel_each.rb:66:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/testing/isolation.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/test_case.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.8/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:405:in `<module:ActionController>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.8/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.1/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb:9:in `<module:ControllerExampleGroup>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.1/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb:6:in `<module:Rails>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.1/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.1/lib/rspec/rails/example.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.1/lib/rspec/rails.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /home/dyego/Documents/coisas/rails/workspace/podcast-central/spec/spec_helper.rb:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4/lib/spork.rb:24:in `prefork'
    from /home/dyego/Documents/coisas/rails/workspace/podcast-central/spec/spec_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:460:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:460:in `block in requires='
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:460:in `map'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:460:in `requires='
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:27:in `block in configure'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:26:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:26:in `configure'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:21:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
Run options: --seed 9081

# Running:



Finished in 0.001545s, 0.0000 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

0 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Nitrous.io log:

```
No examples found.                                                                                                                                                   


Finished in 0.00009 seconds                                                                                                                                          
0 examples, 0 failures                                                                                                                                               

Randomized with seed 46830
```

So, basically I'm able to run tests on nitrous.io but not on local computer and the only main difference between these two enviroments that I could find is the ruby version:

Nitrous.io: ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux]
My Computer: ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Apparently this file is causing the error "/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/parallel_each.rb:67:in "

It's within the 2.10 ruby's folder

On nitrous.io I don't have this file, instead there is a different version "/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1$"

Anyone experienced something similar?

Thanks.

EDIT

I found some similar questions but they were either unsolved or unanswered

Example: [Rails - ruby/2.1.0/minitest/parallel_each.rb:67:in '<class:Unit>': undefined method '_run_suites' for class 'Minitest::Unit' (NameError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807969/rails-ruby-2-1-0-minitest-parallel-each-rb67in-classunit-undefined-met)

[Ruby On Rails - rspec fails after include gem 'minitest'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849664/ruby-on-rails-rspec-fails-after-include-gem-minitest)

Comment: How are you running your tests on your local machine - the stacktrace looks like you are using MiniTest rather than Rspec.

Comment: Hello raptor, as you said I was using minitest and after I removed it, I was able to run the tests ;) . but took me almost 3 days to realize that ....

Answer (score 0):

I was using minitest and after I removed it, I was able to run the tests ;) . but took me almost 3 days to realize that .... – SupimpaAllTheWay